# Prevent record from being inserted in the table in After Trigger

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, trigger

I have a scenario where I have to insert a record in `TableA` only if the `RecordId` exists in `TableB`.

I have written an Instead of Trigger on `TableA` for `Insert`, in which I am checking if the `RecordId` exists in `TableB`, and if it exists then I am allowing the `Insert` in `TableA` by explicitly inserting the record in `TableA` in that trigger.

I want to know can I write an After Trigger on `TableA`, in which I do the same check, and in case if `RecordId` is not found in `TableB` then I delete the inserted record from `TableA`.

**My question is If I fire delete query on `TableA` for the same record which I am inserting will it work, and prevent the record from being inserted from the `TableA` actually.**

Comment: Why not just use a Foreign Key? And if the first trigger prevents a row from being inserted, then in what use case would the `AFTER` trigger ever be needed?

Comment: Agreed with John - how is it possible that the INSTEAD OF trigger would succeed and allow the insert but the AFTER trigger would roll it back? How could a check pass and then an instant later fail?

Comment: @John we are restricted to put any such constraint on DB from admin.

Comment: @Aaron I didn't mean to implement both triggers, I have to implement only one. Both instead of and After trigger are able to solve my problem. can you suggest me which one to use as a best practise,in this scenario?

Comment: I prefer INSTEAD OF because at least logically you are preventing something from happening instead of letting it happen and then rolling it back. I wrote about this too: http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3139/improve-sql-server-efficiency-by-switching-to-instead-of-triggers/

Comment: @Niraj So, are you saying that your admin will not allow a Foreign key, but will allow a trigger that prevents inserts? Have you actually discussed this with her/him?

Comment: If the admin prefers a trigger to a check constraint, you might need a new admin.

Answer (score 1):

I do not see this as the most desirable implementation. Using a Foreign Key constraint to enforce correctness is (in my opinion) **much** better than  writing code to handle such issues.

However, regarding your question, **Yes**, TableA can have both an `INSTEAD OF` trigger and an `AFTER` trigger.  (In fact it can have several `AFTER` triggers.)

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx outlines some rules, including:

1. If constraints exist on the trigger table, they are checked after the `INSTEAD OF` trigger execution and before the `AFTER` trigger execution. **If the constraints are violated**, the `INSTEAD OF` trigger actions are rolled back and the `AFTER` trigger is not fired.
2. An `AFTER` trigger is executed only after the triggering SQL statement has executed successfully. This successful execution includes all referential cascade actions and constraint checks associated with the object updated or deleted. *An `AFTER` trigger will not recursively fire an `INSTEAD OF` trigger on the same table.*